# Using Python, extracting previous and next item of a matrix in row and column

Tags: python, list, matrix, arraylist

I have a matrix of lists of the following form.

---

`Matrix=[[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]],
 [[12,13,14],[15,16,17],[18,19,20],[21,22,23]],
 [[24,25,26],[27,28,29],[30,31,32],[33,34,35]]]`

for example i choose `Matrix[i][j]`, so i want to extract `Matrix[i-1][j-1], Matrix[i-1][j], Matrix[i-1][j+1], Matrix[i-1][j-1], Matrix[i][j-1], Matrix[i][j+1], Matrix[i+1][j-1], Matrix[i+1][j] and Matrix[i+1][j+1]`

can i do it in a loop?

Comment: I'm sure you can, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean `Matrix[i-1][j-1], Matrix[i-1][j], Matrix[i-1][j+1], Matrix[i][j-1], Matrix[i][j], Matrix[i][j+1], Matrix[i+1][j-1], Matrix[i+1][j] and Matrix[i+1][j+1]`?

Comment: yes, i am. but if i put an integer instead of 'i' and 'j' i can't write it in a loop - @DmitryPolonskiy

Comment: i want to receive 8 elements around an element. if a choose Matrix[2][1], answer should be Matrix[1][0], Matrix[1][1], Matrix[1][2],..., Matrix[3][1], Matrix[3][2] @user2314737

Comment: it's actually 9 elements

Comment: yes, Do you know what should i do? @DmitryPolonskiy

Comment: yes one second I am posting an answer

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy 9 elements if you want the central element, too. Otherwise it's just 8. Have fun coding the loop!

Comment: all done @user2314737 check it out =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you want.

First let's get all the unique combinations of `i & j`

```
import itertools
import numpy

def uc(nums):
    return set(itertools.product(*((num+1, num-1, num) for num in nums)))

nums = [1,2]

idx = uc(nums)

>>>{(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)}

m = np.array(Matrix)

array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35]]])
```

Then we can use the awesome feature of tuple indexing from `numpy` to select all the rows that match these indexes.

```
[m[idx_] for idx_ in idx]

[array([3, 4, 5]),
 array([18, 19, 20]),
 array([21, 22, 23]),
 array([27, 28, 29]),
 array([15, 16, 17]),
 array([33, 34, 35]),
 array([30, 31, 32]),
 array([ 9, 10, 11]),
 array([6, 7, 8])]
```

Comment: Thanks. Think this is Right. @Dmitry Polonskiy

Comment: sorry i didn't know that.@Dmitry Polonskiy